# Adding values in filestream

Tags: c++, filestream

For example i have a notepad for numbers.

> 1 2 3 4 5

Then i want to add 4 in the third line which is 3 so that its new value will be

> 1 2 7 4 5

Question is how can i do that?
Please help me thank you!

```html
string add;
 cout<<"Enter value to be added: ";
 cin>>add;
 fstream file;
  file.open("quantity.txt");
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Do you want to add the number and put the result back into the file or just show it?

Comment: I want to add the number and put the new result into the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have not been accurate enough with your question, but I think this is something like what you expect:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    std::string filename;
    std::cout << "Enter name of file to modify: ";
    std::cin >> filename;

    std::ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open(filename);
    if(inputFile.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file \"" << filename << "\" for reading\n";
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned offset;
    std::cout << "Enter offset to modify: ";
    std::cin >> offset;

    int toAdd;
    std::cout << "Enter value to be added to line #" << lineNumber << ": ";
    std::cin >> toAdd;

    std::vector<int> nums;
    for(;;) {
        int num;
        inputFile >> num;
        if(inputFile.eof())
            break;

        nums.push_back(num);
    }

    inputFile.close();

    if(offset >= nums.length()) {
        std::cout << "Offset " << offset << " out of bounds!\n";
        return 1;
    }

    nums[offset] += toAdd;

    std::ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open(filename);
    if(outputFile.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file \"" << filename << "\" for writing\n";
        return 1;
    }

    for(int num : nums)    // Warning: C++11
        outputFile << num << ' ';

    outputFile.close();
}
```